# Replacement for deprecated ViewContainerRef.parentinjector

Tags: angular

After I upgraded to Angular 7, I am getting `parentInjector is deprecated: No replacement` in my code. As this is clearly deprecated, why there is no update available or do the Angular team just missed to add that in documentation?

I am using the injector to dynamically add components in dom.

```
const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(modalClass);
const ref = factory.create(this.vcr.parentInjector);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As this is clearly deprecated, why there is no update available or do the Angular team just missed to add that in documentation?

It was an API mistake and should have been a private member. There is no hierarchical structure to the dependency injector. You can not get a *parent* injector from an *injector* anywhere in Angular.

> I am using the injector to dynamically add components dom.

You should be using `this.vcr.injector` instead. If this change breaks your source code, then need to change your source code.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25174

Request to deprecate API: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25092#discussion_r205181787

Comment: But lets say I need to run `ChangeDectorRef#detectChanges` for the *host* component, not the one with the directive (which is in the host's template). How can I do this without access to the parent injector?

Comment: Okay, I can answer myself. Just by injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` in the Directive constructor.